# Javascript date validation

Tags: javascript, date

I am using a javascrpit for a data validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verifyDate(sender,args){
        var d = new Date();            
        d.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1)
        if (sender._selectedDate > d  )
        {
            alert("Error");
            sender._textbox.set_Value('')
        }
    }
</script>
```

the above validation is for not allowing tomorrow date.

but now i want the date to be allowed only from last month date till today date

for ex it should allow from 09/31/2013 till today
how to do?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: if var selectedDate = "09/31/2013" it should allow only till "08/31/2013" and should mot allow tomorrow date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the validation script which validate :

1-> Selected date should be not be greater than today date

2-> Selected Date should be between current month and last month

```
var selectedDate = "12/31/2013 "
dt = new Date(selectedDate);
console.log(dt);
// Tomorrow Date
var nextDate=new Date();
nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()+1);
console.log(nextDate)
// Date till last one month
var pastDate=new Date();
pastDate.setDate(pastDate.getMonth()-1);
console.log(pastDate)
// Compare
if(dt >= nextDate || dt < pastDate){
     console.log(" PUt till current date")
}else{
     console.log(" date is accepted")
}
```

Hope you want same.Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/YRxpF/1/

Comment: if var selectedDate = "09/31/2013" it should allow only till "08/31/2013"

Comment: @user2380844 : what exactly do u want in validation.. Selected Date should be within 1 month date from today or something else?

Comment: validation is : if curerent date is "09/31/2013" validation should allow only "08/31/2013" to "09/31/2013"

Comment: @user2380844 : I have updated my answer,please check,I hope you want same or let me know if you want some other validation

Comment: hey thank you for replying.. i am using today date "09/01/2014" so it should validate "09/1/2014" till "09/31/2013" but its not working

Comment: "09/31/2013" is 3 months back date, but in your question you want to validate till last month only...

Comment: thank you with you help i found answer. . but one  or two changes var selectedDate = "01/09/2014 "
dt = new Date(selectedDate);
document.write(dt);
// Tomorrow Date
var nextDate=new Date();
nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate());
document.write(nextDate)
// Date till last one month
var pastDate=new Date();
pastDate.setMonth(pastDate.getMonth()-1);
document.write(pastDate)